# HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error при попытке взаимодействия JQuery.soap-запроса с WCF-службой

Tags: jquery, .net, wcf

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь отправить данные через JQuery.soap службе WCF, хостом для которой является Windows-служба. Получаю "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" и "Сообщение с Action "" не может быть обработано на стороне получателя из-за несоответствия ContractFilter на EndpointDispatcher. Возможно, это связано с несоответствием контрактов (несогласованность действий на стороне отправителя и получателя) или несоответствием привязка/защита на стороне отправителя и получателя.  Убедитесь, что отправитель и получатель имеют один и тот же контракт и одинаковые привязки (включая требования к защите, например, Message, Transport или None)." Скрипт и код WCF приведены ниже. Просьба помочь.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Cars_Data
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int id;
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://C_M_Service")]
    public interface ICMInterface
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/GetCars")]        
        [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]

        string GetCars(int Cars_Data);
    }

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]    

    public class Car_market : ICMInterface
    {      
        public  string  GetCars(int Cars_Data)
        {            
            return("<result>\"OK\"</result>");            
        }
    }


    $.soap({
            url: "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/",
            method: "GetCars",            
            soap11:true,
            data: "<id>123</id>",
            error: function (soapresponse) {
                alert("Oh no is error: "+soapresponse.toString());
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert("OK "+result.toString());
            }
        });

<system.serviceModel>   
    <services>
    <service name="C_M_Service.Car_market">      
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service" binding="webHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="" contract="C_M_ServiceReference1.ICMInterface"
        name="WSHttpBinding_ICMInterface1">        
        <identity>
          <servicePrincipalName value="host/PC" />        
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      </service>
    </services> 
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" httpHelpPageEnabled="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>  
    </behaviors>    
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">   
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>

Добавил указание версии SOAP:
    <bindings>
          <customBinding>
             <binding name="Soap11">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
                <httpTransport />
             </binding>
          </customBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял, в чем у вас конкретная проблема. Намекну еще раз.

Вот у вас определение вашего Action в службе: `[OperationContract(Action = "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/GetCars")]`

Вот Action, который вы передаете службе: `method: "GetCars",`

Проверьте еще раз, совпадают ли эти строки.

Comment: Нет, не совпадают. Имеете в виду, что надо указывать method как method: "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/GetCars"?

Comment: Разумеется, они должны совпадать.

Comment: Пробовал выставлять оба значения и http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/GetCars, и GetCars - не помогает. Всё равно в fiddler SOAPAction: GetCars. Меня смущает, что в формируемом JQuery.soap сообщении нет тэга <GetCars>.

Comment: Если посмотреть в документацию (https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap/blob/master/README.md), то там будет видно, как правильно задавать SOAPAction. Попробуйте задать его там.

Comment: Задал SOAPAction: "GetCars". Не помогло.

Comment: Прочитайте свой OperationContract еще раз и задайте правильный SOAPAction

Comment: Смотрю в fiddler: SOAPAction: http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/GetCars. Выдаётся "Сообщение с Action "" ...".

Comment: Тогда возвращаемся к ответу номер 1 и смотрим, какую версию SOAP вы используете.

Comment: Версия 1.1. Action в заголовке SOAPAction.

Comment: Вы уверены? Приведите секцию `system.serviceModel` из вашего web.config

Comment: Добавил в вопросе.

Comment: В этом файле нигде не написано, что используется версия 1.1. Добавьте явную конфигурацию биндинга, с указанием messageVersion.

Comment: Добавил описание bindigs в вопросе. В конечных точках указал bindingConfiguration="Soap11". На стороне клиента это ничего не дало. После добавления в конфигурацию службы она перестала запускаться.

Comment: Разумеется. Вы же настроили customBinding - а используете webHttpBinding.

Comment: Павел, данные доходят, огромное спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли.

Answer (score 0):

WCF определяет Action исходя из версии конверта.

Для Soap 1.1 Action определяется по заголовку HTTP SOAPAction, для Soap 1.2 action записывается в заголовке Content-type.

Если вам не нравится такой подход - включите WS-Addressing и передавайте заголовок Action в конверте.

Еще можно установить behavior, который переопределит OperationSelector - тогда WCF больше не будет искать Action. К примеру, можно выбирать операцию по корневому элементу тела сообщения - это довольно удобно, поскольку в стандартной схеме в теле сообщения корневой элемент - это и так имя метода.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! В fiddler у меня SOAPAction: GetCars. Что же не так?

Comment: Не нужно указывать свойство Action в коде службы, если передаётся заголовок SOAPAction?